# How to enable mulit dex ,when building apk in AOSP?

Tags: java, android

No able to do mulitdex in Android AOSP build. Successfully created multi dex in android studio but not able to do the same using AOSP build

It gives me below error:

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 84626; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

But not sure how to use this multi dex option in AOSP build using make file

Comment: Use Proguard. The problem here is the limit on methods Android enforces. You can also set this up in the Gradle. Not sure how, but its a simple one liner.

Comment: I am able to do that using grade , but the same gives me above error  while building in aosp , it gives me above error. Can u help with progaurd changes of the same ? Or please give me a hint to remove unused classes . .

Comment: Great buddy, you might want to post an answer about your experience of how you solved it. That might help someone in the future who stumbles here.

Comment: 1)Extend your application with android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication instead of just "Application".          2)  In Android.mk file use  : LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --multi-dex

Comment: @pradeep.k unknown options: --multi-dex