# ERROR: Dex writing phase: classes.dex has too many IDs. Try using multi-dex

Tags: makefile, android-source, android-multidex

I'm integrating my app into Android AOSP source code to compile. I encountered an issue said as below:

**ERROR: Dex writing phase: classes.dex has too many IDs. Try using multi-dex**

It worked fine in android studio. My app setting looks like:

```
    public class App extends MultiDexApplication{
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    }
```

Setting in mainifest.xml

```
android:name=".App"

dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
defaultConfig {
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I found a solution at here:
[How to enable mulit dex ,when building apk in AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300028/how-to-enable-mulit-dex-when-building-apk-in-aosp)

but it didn't work.

My mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --multi-dex --main-dex-list=$(mainDexList) --minimal-main-dex

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := multidex-1.0.1:libs/multidex-1.0.1.aar
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue...

Comment: Yes. I did. Added below two lines into your mk files.
LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --multi-dex --main-dex-list=$(mainDexList) --minimal-main-dex
LOCAL_JACK_FLAGS += --multi-dex native

Comment: So you are using NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below two lines into your mk files. It should work.

```
  LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --multi-dex --main-dex-list=$(mainDexList) --minimal-main-dex
  LOCAL_JACK_FLAGS += --multi-dex native
```

Comment: Are **mk** files preferred over CMake?